# How to mark Firefox OpenSearch search engine addon as mobile compatible?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, compatibility, opensearch, fennec

I have developed several search providers (not XPI add-on but just an XML file) for Firefox, but can't install any in Firefox Mobile, getting incompatibility error:

> This search engine isn't supported by Firefox and can't be installed.

How to make them compatible? I didn't found anything compatibility-related on the Dev Hub.

Answer (score 0):

The application IDs for Firefox Mobile are:

- `{a23983c0-fd0e-11dc-95ff-0800200c9a66}` (Firefox Mobile with XUL user interface)
- `{aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}` (Firefox Mobile with native user interface)

You should add the corresponding `targetApplication` sections to the `install.rdf` file of your package.

Comment: Am I correct that this is for full Firefox addin? But my search providers are just an XML files, only it.

Comment: @abatishchev: You didn't quote the message you are getting so I assumed that you were packaging your search plugins as XPI files. Feel free to provide additional details in your question... How are you installing your search plugin?

Comment: I'm opening the addon page on the hub from my FF Mobile (Android) and clicking Install. Error (actually in Russian): This search engine isn't supported by Firefox and can't be installed.

Comment: @abatishchev: There are two variants of FF Mobile for Android (XUL UI and native UI) and different versions. Also, "addon page on the hub" tells me absolutely nothing about the install method used, [AddSearchProvider()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_search_engines_from_web_pages)? Search engines from mycroft.mozdev.org seem to install just fine in both Firefox variants.

Comment: Don't you know how to distinct them - which one do I have installed?

Comment: And what does "To install an OpenSearch plugin, you need to use the window.external.AddSearchProvider() DOM method" mean?